# C# interface and generic combination. Want to return <T> instead of its base interface

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface

Have stepped on my own toes with what I thought was a very simple piece of code. Code speaks better than words, so here it is.

```
public interface IResponse
{
    IResult Result { get; set; }
}

public class Response<T> : IResponse
    where T : IResult
{
    public T Result { get; set; } 
    // COMPILER ERROR: Property 'Result' cannot be implemented property from interface 'IResponse'. Type should be 'IResult'.
}
```

The compiler does not allow me to do this because IResponse requires Result to be IResult, however I want to take advantage of generics in the implementing class and strongly type the result to T. Is this just not possible, or have I missed something trivial?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They you have to make `IResponse` generic too:

```
public interface IResponse<T>
    where T : IResult
{
    T Result { get; set; }
}

public class Response<T> : IResponse<T>
    where T : IResult
{
    public T Result { get; set; } 
}
```

If you want to keep the `IResponse` interface without the generic parameter in tact, you can go even fancier. The below has the two interfaces, where the class transparently also implements the interface without the generic parameter:

```
public interface IResponse
{
    IResult Result { get; set; }
}

public interface IResponse<T> : IResponse
    where T : IResult
{
    T Result { get; set; }
}

public class Response<T> : IResponse<T>
    where T : IResult
{
    public T Result { get; set; } 

    IResult IResponse.Result
    {
        get { return Result; }
        set { Result = (T)value; }
    }
}
```

And, if you want to stay closer to your original implementation, you can strip out the `IResponse<T>` and get the following:

```
public interface IResponse
{
    IResult Result { get; set; }
}

public class Response<T> : IResponse
    where T : IResult
{
    public T Result { get; set; } 

    IResult IResponse.Result
    {
        get { return Result; }
        set { Result = (T)value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem with making the interface also generic is that I use it in another class where I dont want it to force me to specify T.

Comment: Yes I thought of that. That's why I've just added the second and third options.

Comment: Just saw you'r update. Looks good and what was buried in my head somewhere. Great stuff! :)

Answer (score 4):

If you 'just' want to "take advantage of generics" you don't need `IResponse`.

The interface is solving another problem, one that is not compatible with your wish. Consider

```
IResponse r = x ? new Response<int>() : new Response<string>();
r.Result = ... // what type?
```

So either make `IResponse` generic too or remove it altogether.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
public class Response<T> : IResponse
    where T : IResult
{
    public T Result { get; set; }
    // COMPILER ERROR: Property 'Result' cannot be implemented property from interface 'IResponse'. Type should be 'IResult'. 

    IResult IResponse.Result
    {
        get { return this.Result; }
        set { this.Result = (T)value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make IResponse generic and change type of Result in IResponse as type paramter passed to this interface.

```
public interface IResponse<T> where T : IResult
{
    T Result { get; set; }
}

public class Response<T> : IResponse<T>
{
    public T Result { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public interface IResponse<T> where T : IResult
{
    T Result { get; set; }
}

public class Response<T> : IResponse<T> where T : IResult
{
    public T Result { get; set; } 
    // NO MORE COMPILER ERROR
}
```